# Phonegap: playAudio is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

i'm a newbie in Android programming.,
now, i'm trying to play sound onclick with phonegap.,
here's my full code.,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="script/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="script/blues.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="script/style.css"/>
    <script src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sound;
        function playAudio(src) {
            sound = new Media('/android_asset/www/sounds/' + src, onSuccess, onError);
            sound.play();
        }
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }
        function onError(e) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="hira_menu.html" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="fade">Upper Menu</a>
    <a href="search.html" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Search</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-d" align="center">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a href="#a" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-position="center"
               data-inline="true"><img
                    data-role="button" src="images/hiragana/base/a.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="a" class="photopopup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-corners="false"
     data-tolerance="30,15">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="images/hiragana/a.gif">
    <div align="center">
        <a href="#" onClick="playAudio('aaa.mp3')"><img data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" src="images/sound.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the problem is i've got this error:

```
CordovaLog     Uncaught ReferenceError : playAudio is not defined
Web Console    Uncaught ReferenceError : playAudio is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/hira_menu.html : 1
```

note: file hira_menu.html is the file before this file.
I've searched the solving on this forum, but it's still not working.,
Anyone knows the solve, please...

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?